# Export chronologically-correct shortlist of Calendar events?

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I’m working up a festival website and wondering if there would be a way to use Calendar to create and export a schedule of entries from the program i.e. users select or add entries to some kind of favourites list which can then be output as a chronologically correct timetable????

Failing this, will Solspace Favourites allow the list to be built but not necessarily in date/time order?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Solspace Favorites to build a list of event entries. Then, you could use this list to create a pipe-delimited string of favorite entry_ids and use that in the `event_id=""` parameter of `{exp:calendar:cal}`. `{exp:calendar:cal}` would then take care of putting events in chronological order.

Keep in mind that you will be able to favorite event entries (i.e. the event entry created in the CP, which is used by Calendar to calculate occurrences), but not specific occurrences. For saving specific occurrences, maybe Freeform or Channel Forms could be used to store this kind of saved data.